# Create Python dictionary from HTML divs using attribute as ids

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have the following html/xml data inside a file and i am attempting to create a dictionary out of that data.

```
<REUTERS TOPICS="YES" LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN" CGISPLIT="TRAINING-SET" NEWID="1">
blah blah...
</REUTERS>
<REUTERS TOPICS="YES" LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN" CGISPLIT="TRAINING-SET" NEWID="2">
blah blah...
</REUTERS>
<REUTERS TOPICS="YES" LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN" CGISPLIT="TRAINING-SET" NEWID="3">
blah blah...
</REUTERS>
#many more like this...
```

I am trying to have a dictionary as

```
 mydict = {1:"blah blah...", 2: "blah blah...", 3: "blah blah...", etc}
```

Where each id number in my dictionary corresponds to the NEWID attribute in the REUTERS tag element.

So far i have this code, but i am clueless on how to use the attribute of NEWID as the key for the key-value pair of my dictionary.

```
mydict = {} 
for reuters_file in os.listdir(reuters_folder):
    with open(reuters_folder+reuters_file) as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, "lxml")
    content = str(soup)  
    val = content.split('<REUTERS')
    mydict[int(key)] = val
```

Comment: Why are you even using `BeautifulSoup` if you're just going to cast it to a string?

Comment: Is `key` supposed to be `NEWID`?

Comment: yes key is suposoed to be the value of NEWID

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')
d = {}

for reuters in soup.find_all('reuters'):
    d[reuters.get('newid')] = reuters.text
```

Comment: How would you create the dictionary from the key-value pair?

Comment: it says xml is not defined. Did you forget to import a dependency for it?

Comment: If you're running the script from repl.it then you'll need to add `import lxml`.

Comment: i have import lxml already. I'm getting an error xml is not defined

Comment: Here `xml` is the content to parse. It's analog of `soup = BeautifulSoup(file, "lxml")` in your code.